# Detailed Java GC logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The sun JVM outputs detailed GC logs to StdOut when the following args are used.

```
 -verbose:gc
 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
 -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

However, I don't want the output in StdOut and I dont really need the detail for every single GC. Is it possible to access the data used for these logs programatically? I would like to be able to log to my own log file the amount of memory allocated/collected and ideally the average object size over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
-Xloggc:log_file_name
```

This file gets reinitialized every time the JVM starts, so dont forget to move it to safe location if you want to keep it for analysis.

A complete list of the many command line options Java understands can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard) for Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping there would be an API so that I could access this data at runtime and write stats every 5 minutes about the volume of data being allocated, collected and promoted.

Comment: A lot of info regarding garbage collection is made available through JMX, open `jconsole` and check out the different mbeans a JVM exposes.  There are several questions here on SO regarding JMX and GC as well.  If you understand german this article and the related code contain some interesting ideas http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/jmx-gc.htm

Comment: As of JVM 1.6.0_34 you can have java rotate the logs.  
`-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<number of files> 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=<size>`  
Note that all three options are required. other tips here: http://jyates.github.io/2012/11/05/rolling-java-gc-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JMX Beans for Memory Pools and GC instead. They have the advantage that you get counters wich you can query on a free schedule. The disadvantage is, that they differ for various VM vendors, versions and GC settings.

For example

```
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=Copy
  CollectionCount, ColletionTime, LastGCInfo[1].duration,memoryUSageBefore/After
java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=MarkSweepCompact
  CollectionCount, CollectionTime, LastGCInfo[1].duration,memoryUSageBefore/After
java.lang:type=Memory
  HeapMemoryUsage[1].commited,init,max,used
```

Comment: Are the CollectionTime values from JMX reliable?  When I compare them to  times added up from the gc.log and I find that the JMX values drastically undercount time spent in GC.